How to set up proper internal DNS servers?
I am currently running 3 bind9 servers on 3 different machines on my home lab. The network topology is roughly as following:

All 3 bind9 servers are both authoritative zone servers and recursive DNS server. They don't answer query from the internet. They serve the internal clients as well as remote VPN clients. The DHCP server assigns them to clients correctly. I see them listed in the client network configs. dig from any of them replies properly.
All the clients are either IoT, linux or macOS, iOS or iPadOS based.
However, the clients cannot look up the internal application servers while the primary DNS server offline.
How could I set them up properly so the DNS service can failover to secondary DNS servers?

What traffic do you see from clients when the primary server is down? Do they actually send queries to the backup servers or do they immediately give up?

If you have multiple DNS servers configured on the clients it’s likely a configuration issue server side. Include your zone configurations and named config in your question

The clients have no problem with recursive DNS functions. Only the private zone is out of service. I.e. Google.com is resolutable but time out for home.lab.

@pzkpfw Sorry for the late reply. I have missed your comment.
Here are the files:

primary


named.conf https://pastebin.com/fjNEijX2
named.conf.options https://pastebin.com/4N0EuxuM
named.conf.local https://pastebin.com/ihGKLfYS
db.home.ngs https://pastebin.com/sNYr3b7m


secondary


named.conf https://pastebin.com/FYzmGvXm
name.conf.options https://pastebin.com/WDHfT0VM
name.conf.locals https://pastebin.com/TrCmvibb


@crackpot have you confirmed that your clients are getting all three dns servers (50,65,40)? when the primary DNS server is down, what do you get if you dig the other two servers? what do the logs say server-side?

@pzkpfw Yes, I see all 3 in the network config. And running dig individually against all 3 returns expected values. I haven't viewed the server-side logs yet. Thanks for letting me know they exist. I will look into them.
